wrong similarity search result on chroma db
I am appending each row in csv file into chromadb with format, such as below;
#Acme1 prod #Acme1 line, AC1
#Acme2 prod #Acme2 line, AC2
embedding = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")

Chroma.from_documents(documents=docs, embedding=embedding, persist_directory=persist_directory)

While retrieving data with the query below;
cli = chromadb.PersistentClient(path=persist_directory)
collection = cli.get_or_create_collection(name="langchain")

results = collection.query(
            query_texts=["Acme1 prod"],
            n_results = 2)

system calculate wrong similarity scores, as below;
#Acme1 prod #Acme1 line, AC1 - score: 0.5336291790008545
#Acme2 prod #Acme2 line, AC2 - score: 0.531871497631073
As you can see from the result, system calculates "Acme2 prod" is more similar than "Acme1 prod" regarding my query.
What is wrong here?
Thank you for your helps.
System should calculate distance for "Acme 1" is more similar regarding my query
